# Unknown Phone Cable to Internet

Tags: wiring, ethernet, telephone, internet

My home is old (like over 20 years), and we just renovate it last years. Later on, I started to use another part of my home, and that part wasn't touched for a long time (not during the renovation). I took a router to one of the socket and try to get internet, and I found a telephone socket. After opening the socket lid, I found a pipe with 8 cables in it (just the same as ethernet) with weird color code that I don't recognize(I'm sure it's not ethernet color code, and I cannot find anything about it anywhere). Two of them is already connected to the telephone socket and 6 remained unused. I attached the picture:
[image: The cables that I mentioned]
I see brown, black, red, white, purple, green, yellow, and blue(yellow and blue is attached to the telephone socket). All of them has solid color. Nothing is written on the outer pipe. What is this type of color code? Is it possible to be converted to ethernet cable so I can access internet?

Comment: That's not suitable cable for ethernet. It was fine for telephone, and that's all it was being used for when it was used. If you want ethernet here, you'll need to upgrade (replace) the cable.

Comment: The pairs are not split on the normal colors. Red black , yellow green. Those cables they could work for dsl but I think they top out at 25mb, I got down voted when mentioning cables as this not long ago from the internet only electricians so I will leave as a comment.

Comment: Wires like this are used for various purposes in a home, but most of those wouldn't have a phone jack on the end like this. Example uses: thermostats, security sensors, lawn irrigation, doorbells (typically just a pair). This grade of cable is not suited for ethernet, not to say it won't work at all but it's unreliable. Network cables have pairs of thin wires twisted at specific intervals, this is important to the function.